# Turbolinks and events not firing properly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I'm building a website using a template with lots of embedded jQuery but having issues with turbolinks and events not firing properly.

I have this code below:

```
var uiNav = function() {
    // When a submenu link is clicked
    jQuery('[data-toggle="nav-submenu"]').on('click', function(e){
        // Get link
        var $link = jQuery(this);

        // Get link's parent
        var $parentLi = $link.parent('li');

        if ($parentLi.hasClass('open')) { // If submenu is open, close it..
            $parentLi.removeClass('open');
        } else { // .. else if submenu is closed, close all other (same level) submenus first before open it
            $link
                .closest('ul')
                .find('> li')
                .removeClass('open');

            $parentLi
                .addClass('open');
        }

        // Remove focus from submenu link
        if ($lHtml.hasClass('no-focus')) {
            $link.blur();
        }

        return false;
    });
};
```

Which is handling the folding down menus. The function is initialized with other layout helpers with the following:

```
jQuery(document).on('page:change', function() {
    if (typeof angular == 'undefined') {
        App.init();
    }
});
```

Where App.init just fires uiNav and other functions.

Additionally, I've got the script below to handle adding proper classes to menus, depending on where you are in the app

```
$(document).on('page:change', function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    $('[href="' + url + '"]').closest("ul").parent().addClass("open");
    $('[href="' + url + '"]').addClass("active");
});
```

Now I'm using turbolinks and having massive issues with having it all work. Situation is:

- Open the navmenu, works fine, click the link, follows the link fine
- Open other menu, opens fine, click the link, all good
- Try to open a different menu. Old one that was open closes but nothing else open and script no longer does anything.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong here? I was thinking of just dropping turbolinks but I quite like the smooth transition.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out in the end. Added some console.log to the initializer function to see what it was doing. Turns out it was firing 3 times, 5 times, 7 times and so on...

The solution was to change the initializer to following:

```
jQuery(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
    if (typeof angular == 'undefined') {
        App.init();
    }
    jQuery(document).off('page:change')
});
```

Plus the script adding classes to:

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    $('[href="' + url + '"]').closest("ul").parent().addClass("open");
    $('[href="' + url + '"]').addClass("active");
});
```